# Spring boot: check if GeoJson Point in Polygon fails

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a GeoJson polygon and a point and i want to check if the point is in the polygon.

Classpaths:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
```

I tried with Geometry methods contains and within, but both **failed**.
From google maps I can see, that the point should actually be insinde the polygon.

```
public boolean checkIfPointIsInPolygon(Geometry polygon, Point point) {

   if(polygon.contains(point)) {
     return true;
   }
}
```

```
{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [12.095514088869095, 49.012418152680716],
            [12.095677703619003, 49.01241463418325],
            [12.095661610364912, 49.012400560191],
            [12.09551677107811, 49.01239352319336],
            [12.095514088869095, 49.012418152680716]
        ]
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "coordinates": [
        12.095504206503294,
        49.01242468521154
    ],
    "type": "Point"
}
```

UPDATE: One randomly created point could have been found.

```
{
    "coordinates": [
        12.095571960263833,
        49.01239762127791
    ],
    "type": "Point"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the following code to test your polygon. Your coordinate is really outside the polygon, as seen in the image below.

[image]

You can use [this tool](https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/) to visualize your polygon.

```java
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LinearRing;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;

public class InsidePolygonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[] {
                new Coordinate(12.095514088869095, 49.012418152680716),
                new Coordinate(12.095677703619003, 49.01241463418325),
                new Coordinate(12.095661610364912, 49.012400560191),
                new Coordinate(12.09551677107811, 49.01239352319336),
                new Coordinate(12.095514088869095, 49.012418152680716)
        };

        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
        LinearRing linearRing = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
        Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(linearRing, null);

        Coordinate point = new Coordinate(12.095571960263833, 49.01239762127791); // Coordinate inside polygon

        // Uncomment the line below to test another coordinate
        // point = new Coordinate(12.095504206503294, 49.01242468521154); // Coordinate outside polygon

        if (polygon.contains(geometryFactory.createPoint(point))) {
            System.out.println("Point inside polygon!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Point outside polygon!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this tool is very helpful. I guess the polygon was too small to see it right on google maps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @shimatai answer, if you want points on polygon to give true as well, you can use the following approach:

```
if (polygon.isWithinDistance(geometryFactory.createPoint(point), 0.000000001F)) {
    System.out.println("Point inside polygon!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Point outside polygon!");
}
```

The 0.000000001F is just a tiny threshold(feel free to make it as small as possible) to make the polygon count points on it as inside.

isWithinDistance method draws another polygon on top of the first one with the given distance and basically checks if the given point is within that new polygon